# Sum of areas of traingles APB and CEPD

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles

In triangle $ABC$ points $D$ and $E$ lie on the sides $BC$ and $AC$ respectively, such that $\frac {BD} {DC} = \frac {CE} {EA} = 2.$

$AD \cap BE = P$ (a point). Given that the area of $BPD$ is $252$ more than the area of $APE$, find the sum of the areas of $\triangle APB$ and $CEPD$.

I am looking for a solution without using Menelaus.

Comment: Please add what you've tried to the question.

Comment: and please add a picture

Comment: Yes, @Sahiba is still waiting, and I'd like to know as well, to hear what work you've done thus far.  ("Nothing" is not a valid answer, unless you've actually "done nothing" but in that case, you need to delete your post, come back later when you're ready to participate in doing *your* work.)

Comment: @amWhy In the last four hours, OP has asked 6 questions all without showing any effort. The fact that he has got answers for most of them and the questions have not been closed(yet) gives him enough reason to continue this way.

Comment: I realize this, @Sahiba.  Unfortunately there are answerers who answer *anything* and such.  But it's going to come back and bite this user in the butt.  They've already earned a net negative score for their questions, and will likely soon be blocked from asking questions.  It is terribly frustrating in the meantime.  I've stated much the same as you have here, below a few of their other posts.

Answer (score 1):

Let $DC=3x$ and $AE=3y$. Hence, $BD=6x$ and $EC=6y$.

Now, let $G\in EC$ such that $DG||BE$.

Hence, $EG:GC=2:1$, which gives $EG=4y$ and $AP:PD=AE:EG=3y:4y=3:4$.

Let $F\in DC$,such that $EF||AD$.

Thus, $DF:FC=1:2$, which gives $DF=x$.

Hence, $BP:PE=BD:DF=6x:x=6:1$.

Let $PE=t$ and $AP=3z$.

Hence, $\frac{S_{\Delta BPD}}{S_{\Delta APE}}=\frac{6t\cdot4z}{t\cdot3z}=8$, which says $S_{\Delta APE}=36$ and $S_{\Delta BPD}=288$.

Thus, $S_{\Delta APB}=6\cdot36=216$, $S_{\Delta ADC}=\frac{1}{2}(216+288)=252$

and from here $S_{CEPD}=252-36=216$, which gives the answer: $432$.

Comment: i am confused how to show the first claim in your answer.

Comment: @Neeraj Rattehalli I added something. See now, please.

Comment: Where did the answer go?

Comment: @Neeraj Rattehalli $216+216=432$.

Comment: wont DF=2x because DC is 3x

Comment: @Neeraj Rattehalli I fixed a typo. See now.